# How can i give dynamic padding to an Entry in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, padding

How can i give dynamic padding to an Entry in Xamarin forms which looks same on every mobile screen size?
I am trying to apply padding in this way using EntryRenderer.

Control.SetPadding(20,20,0,0);

On small screen sizes it looks perfect but on large screen sizes it acts different and looks pretty odd.

Answer (score 2):

The [Xamarin.Essentials nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials) has a feature for getting [device display information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-display?context=xamarin/xamarin-forms).

When using the `Xamarin.Essentials` nuget, make sure to follow their [getting started steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/get-started?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=windows%2Candroid).

You could use it to get information about the screen like:

```
var screenWidth   = DeviceDisplay.ScreenMetrics.Width; // in pixels
var screenHeight  = DeviceDisplay.ScreenMetrics.Height: // in pixels
var screenDensity = DeviceDisplay.ScreenMetrics.Density;
```

And then use some combination of that information to set your padding:

```
if(screenWidth <= 400)
{
    Control.SetPadding(20,20,0,0);
}
else if(screenWidth > 400 && screenWidth < 500)
{
    Control.SetPadding(30,20,0,0);
}
else if // continue with whatever conditions need checked
```

Note that I used `screenWidth` in my example, but `screenDensity` may be better suited for your problem. You may have to adjust a few times until you find what works.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a custom Entry where you are able to set the padding, then it's pretty simple.

```
        if (Xamarin.Forms.Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
        {
            Control.SetPadding(20,20,0,0);
        }
        else if(Xamarin.Forms.Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
        {
            Control.SetPadding(40,40,0,0);
        }
```

You can do like this.

Comment: this is not the matter of Phone and tablet. actually padding behaves the different on different phone models like it looks perfect on samsung galaxy s3 but looks odd on samsung galaxy s7.